# Hive partition problems when separator is tab

Tags: hive

Good evening guys,
I need some help for my work project.
I'm creating several staging table on Hive and filling them through Oracle data integrator, but recently I have been stuck on a partition problem.
When I create the table in Hive with field separator `'\t'` `(or \011)`, whenever I try to run ODI mapping, I get the error:

> ODI-1590: The execution of the script failed.  Caused By:
>   org.apache.bsf.BSFException: exception from Groovy:
>   java.sql.SQLException: [FMWGEN][Hive JDBC Driver][Hive]Error while
>   compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10062]: Need to
>   specify partition columns because the destination table is partitioned

I'm sure it's caused by the field separator since using $, ; or any other character doesn't give any problem with the same table.
I tried both with and without `SERDE` and got the same result.
I tried to search on Google and on the official documentation about this problem but couldn't find anything. Am I the only one having problems with partition and tab separator?

Comment: Can you query the table using Beeline? If yes, then it's an ODI bug. Create a ticket on  :*!# &*( Oracle support site.

Comment: I tried an insert and a select, and it worked fine from the client, so I guess ODI has problems reverse engineering tables with tab as separator.